# Button acting funny in Django

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to get a better understanding of DeleteView in Django following [this turorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Ez2NXOX9zY&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBlmzzFcLgDhKTTfNLfX1IK&index=32) and everything works fine except that my button tag doesn't seem to be acting as it should. Instead, I had to use an input tag to make it work, which makes it impossible to place a glyphicon-trash(bootstrap) inside a submit button.

I wonder if it has something to do with me running it on pythonanywhere.com as some websites suggest that a button tag won't work properly as an alternative for `<input type="submit">` under certain conditions.

Here's my code. (I kept both the button tag and the input tag for comparison purposes.)

```
 <ul>
{% for card in  all_cards %}
    <li>{{ card.front }}
    <form action="{% url 'delete-card' card.id %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="card_id" value="{{ card.id }}" >
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="DELETE">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
    </form>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

What puzzles me the most is that when the button tag is clicked, it gives me this error message.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a /like_treasure/ status of 404 (Not Found)
```

*like_treasure is a name of a directory used in a completely different Django project.

Any advice will be much appreciated.

**url.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.static import serve
from . import views
# import PIL


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name="index"),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^card/add/$', views.CreateCard.as_view(), name='add-card'),
    url(r'^card/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/update/$', views.UpdateCard.as_view(), name='update-card'),
    url(r'^card/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.DeleteCard.as_view(), name='delete-card'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,}),
    ]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from .models import Card
# from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

# Create your views here.


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = "index.html"
    context_object_name = "all_cards"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Card.objects.all()

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Card
    template_name = "detail.html"


class CreateCard(CreateView):
    model = Card
    fields = ['front', 'back']

class UpdateCard(UpdateView):
    model = Card
    fields = ['front', 'back']

class DeleteCard(DeleteView):
    model = Card
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

Comment: Show us the url.py file..

Comment: @Boky: both submit buttons post to the same URL...

Comment: Note that the `<input>` element has a *value*, the `<button>` does not. Have you tried giving the button a `value` attribute yet?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know that. Are you sure that the url in the `url.py` file is correct?

Comment: @Boky: because the `<input>` element reportedly works.

Comment: Thank you all for commenting. I tried as suggested, but giving the `<button>` a value doesn't seem to solve the problem. I just added the code for the url.py. I hope it helps.

Comment: Did you try to set form's action as follows: `<form action="/card/{{ card.id }}/delete">`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the file name from "url.py" to "urls.py".

Comment: Sorry, it was a type. The actual file is named as "urls.py".